# Reduzir operação

Tags: javascript

Segue meu código:

```
function yvlcs() {

        var buttonsYv = [];

        document.querySelectorAll('.yv-container-ul li').forEach(function (e) {
            buttonsYv.push(e);
            e.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                if(e.path[0].className == "") {
                    buttonsYv[0].removeAttribute('class');
                    buttonsYv[1].removeAttribute('class');
                    this.className = "yv-btn-active";
                }
            })
        });
    }

yvlcs()
```

Vejam o `buttonsYv[0].removeAttribute('class');` e o `buttonsYv[1].removeAttribute('class');`

Teria como juntar isso em uma linha só, para usar apenas um `removeAttribute('class')` ao invés de dois?

## EDIT

Não queria remover com forEach, pois deste modo eu já fiz, eu quero saber se tem alguma outra alternativa, que seja parecida com css por exemplo, que podemos usar a virgula e pegar mais de um elemento:

```
.elemento1,
.elemento2 {
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Você sempre vai remover apenas os 2 elementos `index[0]` e o `index[1]`, o que acontece caso essa variável tenha mais indices ?

Answer (score 0):

Já que deseja fazer isso a partir de uma certa quantidade o ideal seria utilizar a estrutura de repetição `for`:

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
  buttonsYv[i].removeAttribute('class');
}
```

Comment: Boa noite, foi editada a minha pergunta.,

Answer (score 0):

Para ficar em uma linha apenas você pode fazer assim:

```
buttonsYv.forEach(x => x.removeAttribute('class'));
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Wesley, essa é uma boa saída mas o autor da pergunta não deixa claro se quer remover o atributo de todos os elementos do array. Infelizmente a pergunta é vaga e é difícil de adivinhar o que exatamente o autor quer se ele não se expressar melhor. Dito isso, vale adicionar mais informações na sua resposta para que fique claro o que ela faz e os problemas que podem ocorrem no caso dever serem só alterados o 1º e 2º elementos do array.

Comment: Boa noite, foi editada a minha pergunta.